# How to combine first-child:hover and another element have :before?

Tags: css

I want to make effect on `:before` element when the mouse hover on `first-child` of the list item so the code would be

```
li:first-child:hover ul:before { Code here }
```

To make it more clearly see the code from [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMGZKp) or see below

( i want to make the effect on `.sub1-ul:before` )

```css
* { 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none
}

nav.nav-menu {
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 2000;
}

ul.menu-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 770px;
    height: 90px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    z-index: 2000;
}

li.nav-item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px
}

li.nav-item > a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 11px;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #5aabe1;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out;
            transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out
}

li.nav-item:hover > a {
    background-color: #fffffc;
    color: #3498db
}

/* ========== START SUB1 ========== */

.sub1-ul:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    border-width: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
    border-color: #0f0 #0F8FD3 transparent #000;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.sub1-ul li:first-child:hover .sub1-ul:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    top: 15px;
    left: 3px;
    border-width: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
    border-color: #0f0 #000 transparent #000;
    border-style: solid solid solid solid;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
}

.sub1-ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    margin-top:-10px ;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
       -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
            transition: all .2s linear
}

li.nav-item:hover .sub1-ul {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity: 1
}

.sub1-item {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    left: -36%;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    -webkit-transition:margin-left 200ms linear;
       -moz-transition:margin-left 200ms linear;
            transition:margin-left 200ms linear
}

.sub1-item:hover {
    margin-left: 4px;
}

.sub1-item .sub1-a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background-color: #0F8FD3;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 17px;
    border-left: 6px solid #4C4C4C;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms,
                        border-left-color 400ms,
                        padding-left 200ms linear;
    
       -moz-transition: background-color 400ms,
                        border-left-color 400ms,
                        padding-left 200ms linear;
    
            transition: background-color 400ms,
                        border-left-color 400ms,
                        padding-left 500ms linear
}

.sub1-item:hover .sub1-a {
    padding-left: 6px;

    border-left-color: #e67e22;   
}

/* ========== START SUB2 ========== */

.sub2-ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
       -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
            transition: all 400ms ease
}

.sub1-item:hover .sub2-ul { 
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    opacity: 1
}

.sub2-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}

.sub2-item:hover {
    border-left-color: #4c4c4c
}

.sub2-item .sub2-a {
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    padding-top:15px;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
    -webkit-transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 200ms ease-in
}

.sub2-item:hover .sub2-a {
    border-left-color: #4c4c4c
}
```

```html
<nav id="sec-nav" class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="menu-wrapper">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu1 </a>
      <ul class="sub1-ul">

<!-- ===== Want to move before with this list item when mouseover on it =====-->

        <li class="sub1-item">
          <a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
          <ul class="sub2-ul">
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

<!--================  Ens of the list item ========================  -->

        <li class="sub1-item">
          <a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
          <ul class="sub2-ul">
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu2 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu3 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: i want to make `.sub1-ul:before` move to right with first li when mouse hover on li.

Comment: Ok i will edit the code and add comment around it.

Comment: Do you want the `:before` (triangle) element to move to the right along with the sub-menu?

Comment: Yes that's all what i need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, i appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the CSS selector to be `.sub1-ul > li:first-child:before` because you want the pseudo-element to be on the first-child so that it moves with the secondary menu.

You then have to adjust

```
.sub1-ul > li:first-child .sub2-ul {
  top: 20px;
}
```

so that the `top` has the right number of pixels to keep it lined up with the top edge of the the first sub-menu.

Slightly hard to explain, but it works.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none
}
nav.nav-menu {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2000;
}
ul.menu-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 770px;
  height: 90px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 2000;
}
li.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px
}
li.nav-item > a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 19px;
  border: 1px solid #5aabe1;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out;
  transition: background-color 400ms, color 700ms ease-out
}
li.nav-item:hover > a {
  background-color: #fffffc;
  color: #3498db
}
/* ========== START SUB1 ========== */

.sub1-ul > li:first-child:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 65px;
  border-width: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
  border-color: #0f0 #0F8FD3 transparent #000;
  border-style: solid solid solid solid;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: left 200ms linear
}

.sub1-ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
li.nav-item:hover .sub1-ul {
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
.sub1-item {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: -36%;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: margin-left 200ms linear;
  transition: margin-left 200ms linear
}
.sub1-item:hover {
  margin-left: 4px;
}
.sub1-item .sub1-a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #0F8FD3;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-left: 6px solid #4C4C4C;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 400ms, border-left-color 400ms, padding-left 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 400ms, border-left-color 400ms, padding-left 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 400ms, border-left-color 400ms, padding-left 500ms linear
}
.sub1-item:hover .sub1-a {
  padding-left: 6px;
  border-left-color: #e67e22;
}
/* ========== START SUB2 ========== */

.sub2-ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
  transition: all 400ms ease
}
.sub1-ul > li:first-child .sub2-ul {
  top: 20px;
}
.sub1-item:hover .sub2-ul {
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
.sub2-item {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.sub2-item:hover {
  border-left-color: #4c4c4c
}
.sub2-item .sub2-a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-left: 5px solid #e67e22;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in
}
.sub2-item:hover .sub2-a {
  border-left-color: #4c4c4c
}
```

```html
<nav id="sec-nav" class="nav-menu">
  <ul class="menu-wrapper">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu1 </a>
      <ul class="sub1-ul">
        <li class="sub1-item">
          <a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
          <ul class="sub2-ul">
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item">
          <a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
          <ul class="sub2-ul">
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sub2-item"><a class="sub2-a" href="#"> sub menu2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sub1-item"><a class="sub1-a" href="#"> sub menu </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu2 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#"> Menu3 </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but if i changed the position of :before ul it will override the li see this codepin to know what i'm talking about [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMNGWz) , once again thanks.

Comment: I looked at your Code Pen. (1) Is the `:before` element in the right place? (2) is the secondary menu in the right place?

Comment: I just need to move triangle with the first list item to right and not moving ul to up, sorry if my question was not clear.

Comment: Wow man! thanks a lot sir, that's exactly what i want. thank for your time, you are genius.